# Why is fgoalattain built-in function not working in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, undefined

I'm trying to invoke an `fgoalattain` function (computing a function minimum with a goal-attainment algorithm) in MATLAB. According to documentation, it should look like this:

```
[X,FVAL,ATTAINFACTOR] = FGOALATTAIN(@objf_1,x0,goal,weight)
```

where `@objf_1` is a function handle for a function defined in `objf_1` m-file and the rest are some arguments I set on my own. They are not important in any case, because evidently MATLAB has a problem with that function, as it throws:

```
>> rospar_4
Undefined function 'fgoalattain' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.

Error in rospar_4 (line 29)
[X,FVAL,ATTAINFACTOR] = fgoalattain(@objf_1,x0,goal,weight)
```

However, I already know that the function works fine on another MATLAB version - R2011b (the one I'm using is R2012b), but with first argument as `char` instead:

```
[X,FVAL,ATTAINFACTOR] = fgoalattain('objf_1',x0,goal,weight)
```

If I try to invoke it like this in mine though, the error is almost the same:

```
>> rospar_4
Undefined function 'fgoalattain' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in rospar_4 (line 29)
[X,FVAL,ATTAINFACTOR] = fgoalattain('objf_1',x0,goal,weight)
```

Any idea how am I getting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a built-in function. You need to install the [Optimization toolbox](http://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fgoalattain.html).

Comment: It is not indeed. I don't know how could I overlook this simple fact, thanks!